# iterate through the rows of a pandas df to generate new df (depending on conditions)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, conditional-statements

I have a df with badminton scores. Each sets of a games for a team are on rows and the score at each point on the columns like so:

0 0 1 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 3 4 4

I want to obtain only O and 1 when a point is scored, like so: (to analyse if there any pattern in the points):

0 0 1 0 1 1 1

0 1 1 1 0 1 0

I was thinking of using df.itertuples() and iloc and conditions to attribute 1 to new dataframe if next score = score+1 or 0 if next score = score + 1

But I dont know how to iterate through the generated tuples and how to generate my new df with the 0 and 1 at the good locations.

Hope that is clear thanks for your help.
Oh also, any suggestions to analyse the patterns after that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `diff`(If you need convert it back try `cumsum`)

```
df.diff(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[1382]: 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1
1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Wow very clean ! Thanks very much :)